# Why CSS function pow() used to calculate element property does not return a valid value?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I hope this is going to be a trivial problem due to my small experience.
I'm trying to dynamically resize a `<div>` element using CSS3 rules and functions, such as `pow()`, based on other properties value.

I was thinking that maybe something in my code was wrong then I found this examples from MDN site:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pow#examples

html:

```html
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>
```

css:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: calc(1rem * pow(1.5, 4));
}
h2 {
  font-size: calc(1rem * pow(1.5, 3));
}
h3 {
  font-size: calc(1rem * pow(1.5, 2));
}
h4 {
  font-size: calc(1rem * pow(1.5, 1));
}
h5 {
  font-size: calc(1rem * pow(1.5, 0));
}
h6 {
  font-size: calc(1rem * pow(1.5, -1));
}
```

and I tried it in the MDN playground using Firefox 115.0.2 on Ubuntu.

But also here, when I change some argument value of pow() function in CSS rules to modify header font size, I cannot see any change. I tried some variation like replacing 'rem' units with 'px' in the calc() function and other things but no luck. Instead if I remove the pow() and replace with simple multiplication or addition or straight explicit value it properly works.
Running the example code in a stand-alone page, I see in developer console the property value is marked as not valid.

[image]

What's wrong in what I'm doing?

My final target is to dynamically resize a div using a calculation done with pow() based on other properties of the elements. I did it with JS but I'd like to understand if the CSS is viable somehow.

Comment: The page you linked to says `pow` is only supported in Firefox and Safari right now, but you say you're using Firefox. Visiting that Mozilla page in my Firefox browser gives me the same results as you. I guess either that page is wrong about browser support or something else

Comment: I got an answer from page support, seems it is only supported on nightly version of FF, see here https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/26636. But to me this was not clear in MDN docs. Anyway I hope this will change soon in future.

Comment: That's strange because the page says Firefox version 112, and I currently have 115 and it doesn't work. Seems like that page needs updating.